# MVC RoleProvider and Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have implemented my own role provider, and I'm not using the default one. It works to the point that it can tell when someone should or should not be able to view a page.

However, can it do the following:

1. If a user is not logged in, redirect to my login page
2. If a user IS logged in but does not have the correct role, redirect to a different page

I haven't figured out how to do this with the Authorize attribute, all I have is:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
```

Basically I need to redirect to a different page based on what part of the authorization fails.

I've looked to see if it were something in web.config but nothing obvious jumps out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`VoodooChild` answered #1.

For #2 -

What you can do is check if the user is logged on the login page and display a different message or an entirely different page (or even do a redirect to a different action).

Alternatively you can create your own authorization attribute. This will require that you use this attribute everywhere instead of the default `AuthorizeAttribute`

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                               new RouteValueDictionary 
                               {
                                   { "action", "ActionName" },
                                   { "controller", "ControllerName" }
                               });
        }
        else
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

### Update:

Just thought of another method. When a redirect is done to `login` page from a different page, a querystring `ReturnUrl` is also passed. So you can also check if it contains something AND the user is authenticated, chances are the user didn't have permission to view that page.

Comment: +1. didn't know about the `CustomAuthorizeAttribute`, will have to try it out.

Answer (score 7):

Off the top of my head, if you are using FormsAuthentication then to answer your first question - yes If the user is not Authenticated or logged in then it can be redirected to the log on page:

Make sure you have this in web.config file (not sure if you need anything beside this, will look into it..)

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/AccountController/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

To answer your second question: "If a user IS logged in but does not have the correct role, redirect to a different page"

The way we did this was, we used the `System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);` method to get the Roles and based on this we redirected the user to the correct view, after login.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe if a user does not have the proper role to view an action, the user is also redirected to the login page.

Comment: @Omar this is correct, which is a bit strange if you are already logged in. I suppose I could add a redirect check onto the login page but this would feel dirty.