# Custom Authorize Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I'm building my own membership system and I want nothing to do with the MS Membership provider. I've looked around the internet and here on StackOverflow but all I could found was membership providers built on top of the MS Membership provider.

Anyway, I've got almost everything hooked up now, but I'd like to use a custom Authorize attribute which utilized my membership infrastructure. I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664302/mvc-roleprovider-and-authorize-attribute) thread here on the site and I'm trying to do something similar, but I'm not sure that's quiet what I need. So far these are the classes I've got:

**SessionManager:**

```
public static class SessionManager : ISessionManager
{
    public static void RegisterSession(string key, object obj)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = obj;
    }

    public static void FreeSession(string key)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = null;
    }


    public static bool CheckSession(string key)
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[key] != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    public static object ReturnSessionObject(string key)
    {
        if (CheckSession(key))
            return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

**SharweAuthorizeAttribute:** (*I am not really sure if that's actually what I should be doing*)

```
public class SharweAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (SessionManager.CheckSession(SessionKeys.User) == true)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
}
```

Now here's what I need:

1. Is my SharweAuthorizeAttribute class
   correct in the first place?
2. I need to be able to redirect
   unauthenticated users to the login
   page
3. I need to authorize users based on
   their roles (using my own role
   provider) so I would do something
   like:

   ```
   [SharweAuthorize(Roles="MyRole")]
   ```

That's it I guess... Any suggestions are more than welcome :)

**UPDATE:**
Ok I just read that page again and found the solution to question number two:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (SessionManager.CheckSession(SessionKeys.User) == false)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary 
                        {
                            { "action", "ActionName" },
                            { "controller", "ControllerName" }
                        });
    }
    else
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
}
```

Let me know if I got it right please...

Comment: I know this is rather old, but how are you implementing an interface on a static class? Was that allowable 7 years ago?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you got it right (IMO it's safer and simpler to implement a custom membership provider, but it's your choice)

1. Yes, it's correct
2. You do it right
3. You inherit the `roles` property from the `AuthorizeAttribute` base class and you check in your implementation if the user is in the role.

**Edit:** a little more on the roles thing

if you have

```
[SharweAuthorize(Roles="MyRole")]
```

then you can check the Roles property in the AuthorizeCore method

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (SessionManager.CheckSession(SessionKeys.User) == true) {
        if (SessionManager.CheckUserIsInRole( Roles )) // where Roles == "MyRole"
           return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But could you expand on the third point please? I'm not sure I got what you said. A little example would be very much appreciated :)