# How to use custom authorization and authentication in asp.net MVC 3 without using Membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new in Mvc and I am struggling for last 4 days to find any good tutorial for custom authorization and authentication in asp.net MVC 3.

Problem is:-

We are having our own custom User Master table  and also Custom Role Master Table.

Now I want to know How can we authenticate a particular User from Login Page with our Existing Custom User table and also assign rights i:e Role ID from Role master for that Logged In User with out Using Membership Stuff.

The Second thing I want when a User make any request for a Controller, I want to check whether the User's Session is Null or not and also want to check that the Role ID that Logged In User have , whether that Role ID have rights to access that Controller or not.

And also want to implement Role based Access Control . 
For ex:-

**Role 1 can Edit Account of Role 2 and Role 3 

Role 2 can Edit Account of Role 3 only .(Restricted to edit Role 1 Account)**

One solution for that is to make different View and Controller but I don't that is the better Solution.

Please suggest!!!!

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Authorize Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070339/custom-authorize-attribute)

Comment: What have you already tried? `FormsAuthentication`, for example?

Comment: Can you explain why you are not interested in writing custom `MembershipProvider`?

Comment: I have not tried anything in MVC for authentication yet but tried to apply Authorize Action Attribute stuff but doesn't worked out with it.Can you Please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently wrote a custom login solution for MVC. In my case I get an SSO ticket in the query string on the first request to the site. The ticket is verified by a web service call to the ticket service.

Once the identity is verified, I set a normal forms auth cookie to have the identity established on each subsequent call.

In my case I have a custom Identity class, inheriting from `GenericIdentity`. The additional info is passed in the forms auth ticket's user data section. I have an own `Application_AuthenticateRequest` function in global.asax.cs that unpacks the user data and sets the identity.

If you don't have any special data in your forms auth ticket I think that just setting the cookie on successful authentication is enough - the built in versions will take care of examining the ticket and setting the request's identity based on the auth ticket.

Comment: Do u have any solution for this issue:-  **Role 1 can Edit Account of Role 2 and Role 3 
Role 2 can Edit Account of Role 3 only .(Restricted to edit Role 1 Account)**

Comment: Use normal role based auth by checking `UserIsInRole`. You just have to make sure that the current roles are set as part of the thread/request identity.

Comment: Thanx **Andres** but the problem is **Role2** is allowed to edit records, it means **Role2** must be having access for the same **Edit Controller** as for **Role1** that is **Administrator** Role but how can we restrict Role 2 to Edit Role 1 and any other role 2 excluding logged in Role.

Comment: You can't use the normal `Authorize` attribute, it's not flexible enough. Write custom code that checks the conditions as you describe then, by first deciding what roles are allowed/denied for the current operation and then querying if the current user is/isn't in the required roles.