# How to change data string into int for getrolesforuser in asp net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to change `GetRolesForUser` in the ASP .net MVC authorisation string to int. I would like to get value by user type id.

It was because I have multiple tables. So I would like to retrieve value by user type id. Is there any way to change to int for authentication?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using mylatestproject.Models;

namespace mylatestproject.MyRoleProvider
{
    public class SiteRole : RoleProvider
    {
        public override string ApplicationName { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

      public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            attendanceselangorEntities db = new attendanceselangorEntities();
            string data = db.tblusers.Where(x => x.userNm == username).FirstOrDefault().userNm;
            string[] result = { data };
            return result;
        }

        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

This source code has no error, But I want to change it to int.

Comment: What do you mean by "change it to int"? What happens if you just do what you plan to do?

Comment: okay @NicoHaase . how do i want to enable authorization by usertype id instead of userrole name ?

Comment: What about writing the code for it? Where does it go wrong?

Comment: im sorry since im newbie for asp net mvc environment

Comment: i dont know how since i already tried and error occured . ill give what u need to see since i am stuck here 2 days already . @NicoHaase

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried? Which error message have you seen?

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary reasons for creating a custom role provider:

- You need to store role information in a data source that is not supported by the role providers included with the .NET Framework, such as a FoxPro database, an Oracle database, or other data sources.
- You need to manage role information using a database schema that is different from the database schema used by the providers that ship with the .NET Framework. A common example of this would be role data that already exists in a SQL Server database for a company or Web site.

In your case, it seems a custom Authorize filter can form a better solution. some good threads:

- [ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Authorize Attribute with Permission Codes (without roles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264496/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-authorize-attribute-with-permission-codes-without-roles)
- [Custom AuthorizeAttribute with custom authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672335/custom-authorizeattribute-with-custom-authentication)

If using a custom role provider is a must, change your viewpoint and pass userID as string and manage the logic inside `GetRolesForUser` to convert ID back to `int` and return the associate user Roles from your multiple tables.

---

Please comment for more clarification.