# MVC 5: extending Authorization to redirect to an action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I am trying to lock users that are authenticated but not active in their profile page (specific controller/action). By active, I mean that the authorization process needs to check the db to see if the account is active (just a column with boolean data).

This is what I have tried:
However this is getting into a loop.

The idea is:
    if authenticated and active = show the controller/action.
    if not authenticated = show login page (forms auth)
    if authenticated and not active = show profile page.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private ISADietRepository repository;
    public CustomAuthorize()
    {
        this.repository = new SADietRepository(new SADietEntities());
    }
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string user = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            var result = repository.GetVetClinicByEmail(user);
            if (!result.IsActive)
            {
                filterContext.Result =
                new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary{{"Controller", "SADiet"},
                                                                {"Action", "NewCustomer"},
                                                                });
            }
        }
        else
        {

                filterContext.Result =
                new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary{{"Controller", "SADiet"},
                                                                {"Action", "Login"},
                                                                });                                                                
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Guys I just tried this code below. It works as long as the user is authenticated. If the user is not authenticated, it no longer asks for authentication, it just run the action with no user logged in.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private ISADietRepository repository;
        public CustomAuthorize()
        {
            this.repository = new SADietRepository(new SADietEntities());
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                string user = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                var result = repository.GetVetClinicByEmail(user);
                if (!result.IsActive)
                {
                    filterContext.Result =
                    new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary{{"Controller", "MyAccount"},
                                                                    {"Action", "Profile"},
                                                                    });
                }
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);            
        }
    }
```

Comment: `filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` should throw a `NullReferenceException` when no user is logged in.

Comment: Sorry, this line is actually useless. forgot to get rid of it

Comment: If you get rid of it, how do you query the database to see if the user has a flag set?

Comment: it only use it if the user is authenticated, therefore there the string user will not be null!

Comment: However, that is actually not the main problem. I believe that the whole thing is wrong. Did you get I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.
My second code is correct. The problem is that I replaced the attribute instead of adding the new one to decorate the controller.
I was doing this:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
    public class SADietController : Controller
```

instead of this:

```
[CustomAuthorize, Authorize]
    public class SADietController : Controller
```

all sorted!

Answer (score -2):

Pls find the link below that will help to resolve your issue.

[ASP.NET MVC 4 custom Authorize attribute - How to redirect unauthorized users to error page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284729/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-authorize-attribute-how-to-redirect-unauthorized-users-to)

[ASP.NET MVC - How to show unauthorized error on login page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498727/asp-net-mvc-how-to-show-unauthorized-error-on-login-page)

http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/customizing_authorize_attribute

[Custom Authorize Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070339/custom-authorize-attribute)

http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/post/2010/10/16/ASPNET+MVC+Custom+Authorize+Attribute+With+Roles+Parser.aspx

http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/workitem/6333

http://code.commongroove.com/2012/04/20/asp-net-mvc-simple-custom-authorization-by-inheriting-from-the-authorizeattribute/

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for the links, but I have seen at least 5 of the links you suggested. Am I overriding the right things to achieve what I need? Did you understand what I need? Thanks.