# MVC Not Loading Full View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I created a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` which sends users to an error page if they don't have access to view the controller being requested.

The code that redirects them is as follows:

```
Protected Overrides Sub HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext As AuthorizationContext)
    Dim result = New ViewResult()
    result.ViewName = "Error"
    result.ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "oops, you are not allowed"
    filterContext.Result = result
End Sub
```

It redirects them to `~/Shared/Error.vbhtml`, just like it should; however, the page only loads my layout and includes the header `"Error"` but doesn't not load any content of the error page.

The contents of the error page are as follows:

```
@ModelType System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Error"
End Code

@ViewBag.ErrorMessage

<h2>
    Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
</h2>
```

Why isn't it loading the "*Sorry, an error occurred...*" message and how can I make it do so?  Thank you.

Comment: you might want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070339/custom-authorize-attribute) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664302/mvc-roleprovider-and-authorize-attribute) links

Comment: Are you sure that the `~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml` view is being rendered at all? Could there be some other view that is used? Like `Error.cshtml`?

Comment: @Darin:  Yes, because when I change result.ViewName = "Error" to result.ViewName = "Error1," it gives me an error.

Comment: @Yasser:  Can you show me how these apply?  I have an idea but I would like to see an example if possible.

Comment: This doesn't mean that the correct view is being rendered. As I said you could have some other Error.cshtml or Error.vbhtml view somewhere else which is being used.

Comment: @Darin:  I don't know how else to verify.

Comment: Delete the `Error.vbhtml` view and see if you get an error.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov:  It appears as though I don't get the error, so maybe it isn't loading the view at all.  How can I fix it?

Comment: No, it is not loading the view inside `~/Views/Shared`. You probably have some other view inside other location of your site. Search for it.

Comment: your current controller's corresponding View folder might be having a Error.vbhtml view, check for that and remove if present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It redirects them to ~/Shared/Error.vbhtml, just like it should

No, I suspect this isn't the case. You probably have some other `Error.cshtml` or `Error.vbhtml` view that is being rendered. Search your site for the presence of such file somewhere else. Like for example `~/Views/XXX/Error.vbhtml` where XXX is the controller that is currently being executed.

Or you could also explicitly specify which view to be loaded instead of relying on the established probing locations:

```
result.ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml"
```

Comment: You're right.  How can I make it look for specifically "~/Shared/Error.vbhtml?"

Comment: You could specify that explicitly: `result.ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml"`.